# Mysql query to select from where value is X% less or X% more than a value

Tags: php, mysql

What im trying to accomplish is to select all the users who has 20% more or 20% less than `$influencer_account['followed_by']`.

I tried using this code below but it doesnt work.

```
$matchquery = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `publishers_instagram_accounts` WHERE `pid` != '$publisher_id' AND ((".$influencer_account['followed_by']."+(".$influencer_account['followed_by']."*0.20)) <= followed_by) OR ((".$influencer_account['followed_by']."+(".$influencer_account['followed_by']."*0.20)) > followed_by) ORDER BY `id` DESC");
```

Comment: you have an extra bracket. You should code with an editor that matches or finds those missing or extra ones.

Comment: @Fred-ii-all the brackets matches

Comment: That isn't what my IDE shows me for `followed_by) OR (`  use `mysql_query() or die(mysql_error())` to `mysql_query()` and you will see including error reporting http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php

Comment: added inline code formatting

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that you are not doing the maths correctly in your code.
I also recomend to you to use mysqli  functions. See this code, I didn't test it but I think It's going to work:

```
<?php

        $mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "my_user", "my_password", "my_db");

        $query = "SELECT * FROM `publishers_instagram_accounts` WHERE `pid` != :pub_id
            AND (followed_by >= :start ) AND (followed_by <= :end) ORDER BY `id` DESC";

        //You need users with followed_by in the range:
        //      [start,end]
        // where:
        //      start = $influencer_account['followed_by'] - $influencer_account['followed_by'] * 0.2
        //      end = $influencer_account['followed_by'] + $influencer_account['followed_by'] * 0.2
        $percent = 0.2;
        $start = $influencer_account['followed_by'] * (1 - $percent); //20% less
        $end = $influencer_account['followed_by'] * (1 + $percent);//20% more       
        $stmt = $mysqli->prepare($query);
        $stmt->bind_param('idd',$publisher_id,$start,$end);
        $stmt->execute();

        $result = $stmt->get_result();
      while ($row = $result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC))
      {
            var_dump($row);
      }

?>
```

**EDIT:**
If you want to use mysql_query, try:

```
$percent = 0.2;
$start = $influencer_account['followed_by'] * (1 - $percent); //20% less
$end = $influencer_account['followed_by'] * (1 + $percent);//20% more       
$query = "SELECT * FROM `publishers_instagram_accounts` WHERE `pid` !=  $publisher_id AND (followed_by >= $start ) AND (followed_by <= $end ) ORDER BY `id` DESC";
mysql_query($query);
```

Comment: my whole site is in mysql_query although we have plans to move to PDO. How do i use this with my current code?

Answer (score 0):

Try this if it works

```
   $matchquery = mysql_query(
        "SELECT * FROM `publishers_instagram_accounts` WHERE `pid` != ".$publisher_id."
    AND (
         ".$influencer_account['followed_by']."+".$influencer_account['followed_by']."*0.20 <= followed_by OR ".$influencer_account['followed_by']."+".$influencer_account['followed_by']."*0.20 > followed_by
        )
    ORDER BY `id` DESC");
```

Comment: didnt show any change from my code. I have a account with 65203 followers 20% of that is 13040.6 so i should be seeing accounts with no more than 78243.6 followers and no less than 52162.4

Comment: its still showing all accounts rather than the ones who match the followers rule

Comment: there are a few non-matching brackets here. Use an IDE/code editor.

Comment: but now, one is either missing for `<= followed_by)` or it should be taken out. non-matching `= followed_by) OR (".$influencer_account`

Comment: Is it okay to not enclose the data that has been calculate inside the AND operator?

Comment: *"Is it okay to not enclose the data that has been calculate inside the AND operator?"* - it depends on the query and the priority/precedence. OP will have to precise that and try your code now.

Comment: still no change, is the way i approached it correct?

Comment: @aldrin27 i just tried it, it stills shows all accounts

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to do the calculation previously.

```
$reference_value = $influencer_account['followed_by'] * 1.2;
$matchquery = mysql_query(
    "SELECT * FROM `publishers_instagram_accounts` 
     WHERE `pid` != '$publisher_id' AND
         (($reference_value <= followed_by) OR ($reference_value > followed_by)) 
     ORDER BY `id` DESC");
```

I think you were missing a parenthesis.

Comment: also a non-matching bracket, one too many. Use an IDE/code editor.

Comment: I don't see any. Tested here and it works. Can you point that to me?

Comment: My IDE tells me different for these brackets for `followed_by) OR ($reference` use `mysql_query() or die(mysql_error())` to `mysql_query()` and you will see including error reporting http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php

Comment: Worked just fine here... tested directly into a MySQL database and by a php script

Comment: @Berriel the logic is not even the same, $reference_value <= followed_by would be like 14000 <= where it should be 65000+20%

Comment: @user2002220 the logic is just the same as yours... `a + (a * 0.2) == a * 1.2`

Answer (score 0):

You were using != for not equals whereas it should be <>. Also, there was, I think, a misplaced brace in there....

```
$followedby=$influencer_account['followed_by'];

$matchquery = mysql_query("
    SELECT * FROM `publishers_instagram_accounts` 
    WHERE 
        `pid` <> '$publisher_id' AND (
            ( ".$followedby." + ( ".$followedby." * 0.20 ) ) <= followed_by ) 
            OR
            ( ".$followedby." + (".$followedby." * 0.20 ) ) > followed_by )
        )
    ORDER BY `id` DESC;");
```

Comment: This doesnt return any data, cant see why.

Comment: this has an extra bracket, while OP's code had one too, but in another spot.

Comment: There is no difference between `!=` and `<>`